# How to get both image attachment ID and url

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, images

I am using [advanced custom fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) repeater-field to get the image url like this:

```
<?php the_sub_field('billede'); ?>
```

But I also want to get the attachment ID for the image, to be used for something else.

Is this possible? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to change your field to return attachment ID instead of URL, and then when you need the URL, use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) with the ID. The only method I'm aware of to get ID from URL is with a custom SQL query.